# How to change the color of Label in PieChart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, colors, label, pie-chart

I want to change the color of the number shown by the label inside the Doughnut chart from **devextreme-react/pie-chart** library, but I can't.

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fgil.png)

```
    <PieChart
      id="pie"
      type="doughnut"
      palette="Soft Pastel"
      dataSource={opciones}
      centerRender={CenterTemplate}
      onPointClick={pointClickHandler}
    >
    <Series
      argumentField="campo"
      valueField="value">
      <HoverStyle color="red" />
      <Label
        fontColor= "black"
        position="inside"
        visible={true}
        customizeText={customizeLabel}
        backgroundColor="none">
      </Label>
    </Series>
    <Legend
      margin={0}
      horizontalAlignment="right"
      verticalAlignment="top"
      columnCount={2}
      rowCount={15}
      />

    <Export enabled={true} />
  </PieChart>
```

[And this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NysKa.png)

Comment: try to paste in your code, instead of an image, it makes it a lot easier to create an answer for you. Also try to tell what chart library you are using, will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent explanation I used it myself

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RF57yDglDfE